# Java Referring to any object

Tags: java, class, object, variables

I would like to find an object. There is only one object with the variable x=10.
Is it possible? I hope you get what I try to explain... :)

```
if (any object of the class X .getValue() == 10)
...
```

Class X

```
 public int getValue(){
    return x;
    }
```

Comment: You want to find it from where? a list, database, etc? please post some more of your code for clarity.

Comment: In your program you need to somehow store instances of Class X. In order to answer your question you need to tell us what data structure you are using to hold those instances of X

Comment: [Getting all instances of a class](//stackoverflow.com/q/10071065) maybe? Or do you want `static`?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<X> xList = new ArrayList<>();

public static X findXWithValue(List<X> xList, int value) {
 X xWithValue = null;
 for(int i = 0 ; i < xList.size()-1 ; i++) {
  if (value == xList[i].getValue()) {
   xWithValue = xList[i];
   break;
  }
 }
 return xWithValue;
}
```

Br,

Rakesh

Comment: `List xList = new ArrayList<>();` - [Don't use raw types.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Actually the code was not formatted, because of which the <X> was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
public class ObjectFinder {

public static boolean checkObject(Object o, String methodName, int value) {
    return Stream.of(o.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
            .filter(method -> method.getName().equals(methodName))
            .filter(m -> checkType(m, int.class))
            .map(m -> {
                try {
                    return (int) m.invoke(o);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return 0;
                }
            }).anyMatch(v -> value == v);
}

private static boolean checkType(Method method, Class type) {
    return method.getReturnType() == type;
}
```

}

and you can test it in:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(checkObject(new X(), "valueOf", 2));
    }
```